# SingleChildScrollView not working in ErrorWidget.builder

Tags: flutter, error-handling, scroll

I would like to show all the errors raised to the user.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    builder: (context, widget) {
      ErrorWidget.builder = (errorDetails) {
        Widget error = Text(errorDetails.toString());
        if (widget is Scaffold || widget is Navigator) {
          error = SingleChildScrollView(child: error); // <= not scrolling
        }
        return error;
      };
      if (widget != null) return widget;
      throw StateError('widget is null');
    },
    home: const SafeArea(child: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage())),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    throw "build exception";
  }
}
```

But the widget is not scrolling.

I tried to wrap SingleChildScrollView in Scaffold, but it doesn't work.

What should I do to make it scrollable?

Comment: The type of your widget is `FocusScope` so therefore `widget is Scaffold || widget is Navigator` returns false, and `Text(errorsDetails.toString())` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the condition in `ErrorWidget.builder`

```
ErrorWidget.builder = (errorDetails) {
      Widget error = Text(errorDetails.toString());
      if (widget is FocusScope || widget is Navigator) {
        error = SingleChildScrollView(child: error);
      }
      return error;
    };
```

Here `Scaffold` is replaced with `FocusScope` because `MyHomePage` is returning  a widget of type `FocusScope`. Hope it helps.